# Firebase Realtime Database "Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database., and my web app shows a white screen. The browser console shows this error:

> Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card/card';
import './App.css';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const ref = db.ref('main');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        setData(snapshot.val());
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <ul className="horizontal-menu">
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li className="horizontal-menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <Card
          title={item.Title}
          image={item.Image_URL}
          discription={item.discription}
        />
      ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

firebase config file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey:
authDomain:
databaseURL:
projectId:
storageBucket:
messagingSenderId:
appId:
measurementId:
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
```

I changed the config file and import them several times but nothing changed, I wanted to see a card with the info that is in the database

Comment: In your actual code, do you provide values for the keys in `firebaseConfig`?

Comment: yes i provide all the values

Comment: Hmm... in that case it sounds like somehwere else the Firebase SDK is being initialized without those values **or** your call to `initializeApp` is not actually being run before you use the other products. I recommend setting breakpoints on all of those, running in the debugger, and checking if the code indeed executes in the order you expect.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `getDatabase()` in your `App.js` but Firebase is not initialized before that. To ensure Firebase is initialized, it's best to a single instance that you create in `firebase.js` file. Try:

```
// App.js

import { database } from "../path/to/firebase"; // <-- replace with correct path
import { ref } from "firebase/database"

// don't use `getDatabase()` here
useEffect(() => {
  const ref = ref(db, 'main'); // db imported from Firebase config file 

  onValue(ref, (snapshot) => {
    setData(snapshot.val())
  });
}, []);
```